# under the main department menu show all sub menu (role wise) to compare for each role which submenu is given permission

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

```
$data = DB::select("SELECT  d.id, d.role_name, d.display_name_id, d.display_name, d.parent_id, e.display_name AS menu_name FROM
(SELECT a.id, a.role_name, c.id AS display_name_id,c.display_name,c.parent_id FROM application_roles a
JOIN application_default_permissions b ON a.id = b.role_id
JOIN application_security_actions c ON b.action_id = c.id
GROUP BY id, role_name,display_name_id,display_name, parent_id) AS d
JOIN application_security_actions e ON e.id = d.parent_id
WHERE e.parent_id = 0 AND e.id != 0
GROUP BY  id, role_name, display_name_id, display_name, parent_id, menu_name");
```

which i get table like this [image]

I wrote some code to arrange data like this

```
       $my_menu = array();
            $my_menu_opt = array();
            foreach($data as $datas){
                array_push($my_menu,array($datas->id,$datas->role_name,$datas->parent_id,$datas->display_name));
            }


            foreach($my_menu as $_my_menu){
                if( in_array( $_my_menu ,$my_menu_opt ) == false )
                {
                    array_push($my_menu_opt,$_my_menu);
                }
            }

            $menus = array();
            foreach($my_menu_opt as $row){
                $_my_menu_opt = array();
                foreach($data as $datas_m){

                    if($row[0] == $datas_m->id &&  $row[2] == $datas_m->parent_id){
                        array_push($_my_menu_opt,$datas_m);
                    }
                }
                array_push($menus,array($row,$_my_menu_opt));
            }

            return json_encode ($menus);
```

Expected output:

It Department(main menu)

-Supper Admin (role) 
-- Application List (sub menu) 
-- Department Add (sub menu)
-- Role Add (sub menu)

-Admin (role)
-- Application List (sub menu)
-- Department Add (sub menu)
-- Role Add (sub menu)

-Product Entry (role)
-- Application List (sub menu)
-- Department Add (sub menu)

for better understand some table picture are given [image][image][image]

I am stuck on it for 2 days. if any one can help me out.

Comment: share db fiddle link for the same, and what was your output

Comment: [
[
1,
"Supper Admin",
10,
"Application List"
],
[
{
id: 1,
role_name: "Supper Admin",
display_name_id: 1,
display_name: "Application List",
parent_id: 10,
menu_name: "IT Department"
},
{
id: 1,
role_name: "Supper Admin",
display_name_id: 5,
display_name: "Department Add",
parent_id: 10,
menu_name: "IT Department"
},
{
id: 1,
role_name: "Supper Admin",
display_name_id: 8,
display_name: "Role Add",
parent_id: 10,
menu_name: "IT Department"
}
]
],

Comment: In the absence of any aggregating functions, a GROUP BY clause is NEVER appropriate